# Access related fields in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I am setting up an email to send through Marketing Cloud Journey Builder using Salesforce data. I have a child object of Courses called `Request__c`. I would like to display the course name in the email. When I try my code below  `Course__c` return the ID of the course, but when I try `Course__r.Name` it is blank.

Current Output:
Row 1, Course Name is: a1V1L000004k8PJ; Course Name 2nd is:

Desired Output:
Row 1, Course Name is a1V1L000004k8PJ; Course Name 2nd is: Name of Course

```
%%[
    var @row, @rowCount, @numRowstoReturn, @i, @course, @status
    var @rs 
    var @cid 
    set @cid = CaseID
    set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Request__c','Id,Approval_Status__c,Course__c,Comments__c,Case__c, Course__r.Name','case__c','=',@cid)

    set @rowCount = rowCount(@rs)

    if @rowCount >0 then
         for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    set @row = row(@rs,@i)
    set @course = field(@row, "Course__c")
    set @courseName = field(@row, "Course__r.Name")
]%%
    <br><br>
    Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Course Name is: %%=v(@course)=%%; Course Name 2nd: %%=v(@courseName)=%%  <br><br>

    %%[next @i ]%%

    %%[else]%%
    <br><br>
    No rows found
    %%[endif ]%%
```

Comment: I tried another approach using RetrieveSalesforceObjects() to query for the course object itself. 

`if @rowCount >0 then`
`for @i = 1 to @rowCount do`
 
`set @row = row(@rs,@i)`
`set @course = field(@row, "Course__c")`
`set @courseName =  RetrieveSalesforceObjects('hed__Course__c','id,Name','id','=', @course)`

Unfortunately that still returns a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with a bit more digging. I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution, but I am now getting the desired result. In the `FOR` loop I'm now querying for the course name for each `Request__c` record.

Here is the updated loop

```
if @rowCount >0 then
 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

 set @row = row(@rs,@i)
 set @course = field(@row, "Course__c")
 set @courseObj = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('hed__Course__c','id, Name, Course_Number__c','id','=', @course)
 set @courseRow = row(@courseObj, 1)
 set @courseName = field(@courseRow, "Course_Number__c" )
]%%
```

What is new here are three variables. 
`@courseObj`which queries Salesforce for the parent Course record. `@courseRow` returns a single result of the @courseObj collection (even though it should only ever be one). `@courseName` returns the name field.